# np.prod with units from pint.UnitRegistry() - python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find the volume of a voxel with given sidelengths using `pint.UnitRegistry()`
Example of error:

```py
import pint
import numpy as np

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
voxel_size = (81.3, 30.2, 45.3) * ureg.micrometer
volume = np.prod(voxel_size)
```

Results in:

```py
TypeError: no implementation found for 'numpy.prod' on types 
that implement __array_function__: [<class 'pint.quantity.build_quantity_class.<locals>.Quantity'>]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `pint` doesn't support `numpy.prod`. See [docs](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/0.11/numpy.html) for supported `numpy` functions.

The problem is that `pint.UnitRegistry()` returns an object of type `pint.quantity.build_quantity_class.<locals>.Quantity` which is not an array of numbers so `numpy.prod` does not recognize it.

To use `pint` for what you are trying to do try the following...

```
import pint
import numpy as np

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
vox_volume = voxel_size = [81.3] * ureg.micrometer * [30.2] * ureg.micrometer * [45.3] * ureg.micrometer
print(vox_volume)
```